# Improve mdadm RAID5 with SSD Cache

Tags: linux, cache, software-raid, mdadm, bcache

I have the following Setup:
3x 3 TB SATA HDD
With software raid connected to a RAID5
On top of this LVM for snapshots (backup)
And on top of LVM EXT4 formatted.

Actually around 400GB is used.
I have one spare slot within the server.

The write performance of the webserver is quite slow for smaller files. But good/ok for larger ones

```
root@srv1:/home/srvadmin# dd if=/dev/zero of=/root/testfile bs=1G count=1 oflag=direct
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB, 1.0 GiB) copied, 8.93049 s, 120 MB/s
root@srv1:/home/srvadmin# dd if=/dev/zero of=/root/testfile bs=1G count=1 oflag=direct
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB, 1.0 GiB) copied, 25.2487 s, 42.5 MB/s
root@srv1:/home/srvadmin# dd if=/dev/zero of=/root/testfile bs=1G count=1 oflag=direct
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB, 1.0 GiB) copied, 11.0472 s, 97.2 MB/s
root@srv1:/home/srvadmin# dd if=/dev/zero of=/root/testfile bs=100M count=1 oflag=direct
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
104857600 bytes (105 MB, 100 MiB) copied, 2.97071 s, 35.3 MB/s
root@srv1:/home/srvadmin# dd if=/dev/zero of=/root/testfile bs=100M count=10 oflag=direct
10+0 records in
10+0 records out
1048576000 bytes (1.0 GB, 1000 MiB) copied, 15.7935 s, 66.4 MB/s
root@srv1:/home/srvadmin# dd if=/dev/zero of=/root/testfile bs=100M count=20 oflag=direct
```

Now i see different options:
A: add bcache (don‘t know how) and use an SSD as cache
B: Buy an additional disk and create a raid10
C: Buy an SSD, copy all files to it and use the ssd alone without any raid
D: Buy two SSDs and use them mirrored

I guess solution A is the cheapest. I already have a 120GB SSD laying around and the filesystem is in place. But i dont know how to add the SSD for caching. Have you ever did something like this?

The Server is private used, running Ubuntu LTS, the server is also backuped regularely.

Thanks

Edit:

I found this: https://ahelpme.com/linux/lvm/ssd-cache-device-to-a-software-raid5-using-lvm2/

It looks like that lvm offers caching. But im not sure whether i can add caching at this stage i am now.

Edit2:

I guess, i made it!
I followed these two tutorials:
https://www.nocser.net/clients/index.php/knowledgebase/474/Adding-SSD-Cache-to-Existing-LVM.html

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_and_managing_logical_volumes/enabling-caching-to-improve-logical-volume-performance_configuring-and-managing-logical-volumes

And ended up with these commands:
Please check, if the outputs looks feasible:
I have used cache type writethrough instead of writeback, cause i have read that writethrough is the more power failure safe one.

```
root@srv1:~# fdisk /dev/sdd

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.34).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.


Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/sdd: 111.81 GiB, 120034123776 bytes, 234441648 sectors
Disk model: KINGSTON SA400S3
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 2BAB7835-0A17-43DE-83E1-57A2733E4CFD

Command (m for help): n
Partition number (1-128, default 1): 1
First sector (34-234441614, default 2048):
Last sector, +/-sectors or +/-size{K,M,G,T,P} (2048-234441614, default 234441614):

Created a new partition 1 of type 'Linux filesystem' and of size 111.8 GiB.
Partition #1 contains a vfat signature.

Do you want to remove the signature? [Y]es/[N]o: y

The signature will be removed by a write command.

Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/sdd: 111.81 GiB, 120034123776 bytes, 234441648 sectors
Disk model: KINGSTON SA400S3
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 2BAB7835-0A17-43DE-83E1-57A2733E4CFD

Device     Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdd1   2048 234441614 234439567 111.8G Linux filesystem

Filesystem/RAID signature on partition 1 will be wiped.

Command (m for help): t
Selected partition 1
Partition type (type L to list all types): 8e
Type of partition 1 is unchanged: Linux filesystem.

Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/sdd: 111.81 GiB, 120034123776 bytes, 234441648 sectors
Disk model: KINGSTON SA400S3
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 2BAB7835-0A17-43DE-83E1-57A2733E4CFD

Device     Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdd1   2048 234441614 234439567 111.8G Linux filesystem

Filesystem/RAID signature on partition 1 will be wiped.

Command (m for help): w
The partition table has been altered.
Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.
Syncing disks.

root@srv1:~# pvcreate /dev/sdd1
  Physical volume "/dev/sdd1" successfully created.
root@srv1:~# vgextend vg /dev/sdd1
  Volume group "vg" successfully extended
root@srv1:~# lvcreate -n DataLVcache -L100G vg /dev/sdd1
  Logical volume "DataLVcache" created.
root@srv1:~# lvcreate -n DataLVcacheMeta -L100M vg /dev/sdd1
  Logical volume "DataLVcacheMeta" created.
root@srv1:~# lvconvert --type cache-pool --cachemode writethrough --poolmetadata vg/DataLVcacheMeta vg/DataLVcache
  Using 128.00 KiB chunk size instead of default 64.00 KiB, so cache pool has less than 1000000 chunks.
  WARNING: Converting vg/DataLVcache and vg/DataLVcacheMeta to cache pool's data and metadata volumes with metadata wiping.
  THIS WILL DESTROY CONTENT OF LOGICAL VOLUME (filesystem etc.)
Do you really want to convert vg/DataLVcache and vg/DataLVcacheMeta? [y/n]: y
  Converted vg/DataLVcache and vg/DataLVcacheMeta to cache pool.
root@srv1:~# lvconvert --type cache --cachepool vg/DataLVcache vg/md128
  Failed to find logical volume "vg/md128"
root@srv1:~# lvconvert --type cache --cachepool vg/DataLVcache vg/root
Do you want wipe existing metadata of cache pool vg/DataLVcache? [y/n]: y
  Logical volume vg/root is now cached.



root@srv1:~# lvs --all --options +devices vg
  LV                        VG Attr       LSize   Pool                Origin       Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  [DataLVcache_cpool]       vg Cwi---C--- 100.00g                                  0.61   6.47            0.00
  [DataLVcache_cpool_cdata] vg Cwi-ao---- 100.00g
  [DataLVcache_cpool_cmeta] vg ewi-ao---- 100.00m
  data_snap_backblaze       vg swi-a-s---   2.28t                     root         2.99
  [lvol0_pmspare]           vg ewi------- 100.00m
  root                      vg owi-aoC---   2.27t [DataLVcache_cpool] [root_corig] 0.61   6.47            0.00
  [root_corig]              vg owi-aoC---   2.27t
```

If i now try to write to the disk, i get up to 2GB/s

```
root@srv1:~# dd if=/dev/zero of=/home/user12/testfile2 bs=100M count=2
2+0 records in
2+0 records out
209715200 bytes (210 MB, 200 MiB) copied, 0.115231 s, 1.8 GB/s
```

I guess caching is working?
If i execute the exact same command again, the performance is very poor, around 50MB/s.
I guess this is because the file gets written to the RAID5 array, while i try to write to the file right?

Edit3:

Ok, something is going weird...
Everytime i write the same file it gets more slow....

```
104857600 bytes (105 MB, 100 MiB) copied, 0.0622744 s, 1.7 GB/s
root@srv1:~# dd if=/dev/zero of=/home/user12/testfile1 bs=100M count=1
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
104857600 bytes (105 MB, 100 MiB) copied, 0.871399 s, 120 MB/s
root@srv1:~# dd if=/dev/zero of=/home/user12/testfile1 bs=100M count=1
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
104857600 bytes (105 MB, 100 MiB) copied, 4.3185 s, 24.3 MB/s
root@srv1:~# dd if=/dev/zero of=/home/user12/testfile1 bs=100M count=1
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
104857600 bytes (105 MB, 100 MiB) copied, 5.31411 s, 19.7 MB/s
root@srv1:~# dd if=/dev/zero of=/home/user12/testfile1 bs=100M count=1
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
104857600 bytes (105 MB, 100 MiB) copied, 8.95197 s, 11.7 MB/s
root@srv1:~#
```

Last one after waiting ~2mins

```
root@srv1:~# dd if=/dev/zero of=/home/user12/testfile1 bs=100M count=1
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
104857600 bytes (105 MB, 100 MiB) copied, 5.96534 s, 17.6 MB/s
```

Any clue about that? I waited around 20-50 seconds between executing the commands.

Without caching:

```
root@srv1:~# dd if=/dev/zero of=/home/user12/testfile2 bs=100M count=1 oflag=direct
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
104857600 bytes (105 MB, 100 MiB) copied, 11.1603 s, 9.4 MB/s
```

Comment: 50MB/s big file write performance is quite slow, do you know why it is so bad? I would expect something like 250 with modern disks.

Comment: Sorry, i was wrong. I measured it... It was around 70-120MB/s

Comment: 50 MB/s isn’t what I’d call okay, but whatever. By using a write-through cache, you will not improve write performance at all. You cannot improve speed without sacrificing data safety. What you see with `dd` is _buffering_. I suggest using a proper benchmark tool.

Comment: Youre right, it was 120MB/s not 50... I changed the posting. Would there be a drawback in using writeback? Cause im using an SSD for caching and not RAM. therefore i guess if there is a powerfailure, i will not loose the cache, since the SSD will keep the data right? And yes, youre right, it was caching. Without i get ~10MB/s

Comment: I know what the problem was.... Damn... I had a very lvm old snapshot in place. This was more than 6 months old or so. And i gues... the system had to copy all the files to keep in sync with the snapshot... I removed the snapt shot and... The dd transferspeed is 160MB/s within the RAID5 without any cache (i removed the cache)

Comment: If you want to keep using snapshots, consider using LVM Thin Provisioning. It does not suffer from performance degradation. // Remember to add an answer (or delete the question) if you solved your original problem.